# project is running but not displaying

Tags: java

I am working on a project called mycatmychoice which is running but not displaying.  I know i am missing something but not sure what.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.   This is a small part of a larger project but I need to get this piece working first.  I am not receiving any errors but the output is not displaying.

```
package mycatmychoice;


public final class Mycatmychoice {


    public static void main(String[] args) { 

    }
    //variables
    private String name;
    private String breed;
    private String gender;
    private String color;
    private int age;
    public String introducecat;

    //constructor
    public Mycatmychoice(String breed, String name, String gender, String color, int age) {
        this.breed = breed;
        this.breed = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.color = color;
        this.age = age;
    }


//Returns the value of name
    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }

    //Sets the name variable.
    public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    //Returns the value of breed
    public String getbreed() {
        return breed;
    }

    //Sets the breed variable.
    public void setbreed(String breed) {
        this.breed = breed;
    }

    //Returns the value of gender
    public String getgender() {
        return gender;
    }

    //Sets the gender variable.
    public void setgender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

//Returns the value of color
    public String getcolor() {
        return color;
    }

//Sets the color variable.
    public void setcolor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

//Returns the value of age
    public int getage() {
        return age;
    }

    //Sets the age variable.
    public void setage(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void introducecat() {
        System.out.printf("Say hi to %s who is a %d year old %s %s %s  cat \n", getname(), getage(), getgender(), getcolor(), getbreed() );
    }
}
```

Comment: You need some statements in the main method.

Comment: what kind of statements? I am a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `main()` method to include this -

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Mycatmychoice cat = new Mycatmychoice("a", "b", "c", "d", 4);
    cat.introducecat();
  }
```

Then run the program, and see the output.

Also, in your constructor, you probably want the second line as this -

```
this.name = name;
```

instead of -

```
this.breed = name;
```

Here's a good [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html) on the `main()` method. Consider it as the source from which you can kick off other methods in your class -

> The main method is similar to the main function in C and C++; it's the entry point for your application and will subsequently invoke all the other methods required by your program.

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to launch your program then `main()` is the starting point. You will need to instantiate an object of the class, call the getters and setters and then call the display method.

However, more importantly read a book on Java.